# How to fix undefined variables after program runs

Tags: javascript, html, function

The program will ask for all inputs and print everything but the variables all come up as undefined.

This is for a web application tied to a HTML document. No errors are thrown when it runs.

```
function driver(){
    var plan1Code = "S";
    var plan1Cost = 450;
    var plan1Hours = 2.5;
    var plan1Pics = 75;

    var plan2Code = "G";
    var plan2Cost = 750;
    var plan2Hours = 5;
    var plan2Pics = 125;

    var plan3Code = "P";
    var plan3Cost = 1000;
    var plan3Hours = 8;
    var plan3Pics = 225;

    var retName = getName();
    var retPlan = getPlan();
    var retHours = getHours();
    var retPics = getPics();

    var baseCost, totalCost, upchargeTime, upchargeTimeCost, upchargePics, upchargePicsCost;

    if (retPlan == plan1Code){
        baseCost = plan1Cost;
        upchargeTime, upchargeTimeCost = calcTimeUpcharge(retHours, plan1Hours);
        upchargePics, upchargePicsCost = calcPicsUpcharge(retPics, plan1Pics);
    }
    else if (retPlan == plan2Code){
        baseCost = plan2Cost;
        upchargeTime, upchargeTimeCost = calcTimeUpcharge(retHours, plan2Hours);
        upchargePics, upchargePicsCost = calcPicsUpcharge(retPics, plan2Pics);
    }
    else if (retPlan == plan3Code){
        baseCost = plan3Cost;
        upchargeTime, upchargeTimeCost = calcTimeUpcharge(retHours, plan3Hours);
        upchargePics, upchargePicsCost = calcPicsUpcharge(retPics, plan3Pics);
    }

    totalCost = calcTotalCost(baseCost, upchargeTimeCost, upchargePicsCost);
    print(retName, retPlan, baseCost, upchargeTime, upchargeTimeCost, upchargePics, upchargePicsCost, totalCost);

}

function getName(){
    var text;
    var name = prompt("Enter your name");
    if (name == null) {
        text = "Please enter a valid name";
    }
}

function getPlan(plan){
    var plan = prompt("Enter the selected package");
}

function getHours(hours){
    var hours = prompt("Enter anticipated coverage hours");
}

function getPics(pics){
    var pics = prompt("Enter anticipated number of pictures");
}

function calcTimeUpcharge(hours, baseHours){
    upchargeTime = hours - baseHours;
    var price;
    if (upchargeTime>0){
        var upchargeTimeUnits = Math.ceil((upchargeTime)/.5);
        upchargeTimeCost = upchargeTimeUnits * 50;
    }
    else {
        upchargeTime = 0;
        upchargeTimeCost = 0;
    }
    return upchargeTime, upchargeTimeCost;

}

function calcPicsUpcharge(pics, basePics){
    upchargePics = pics - basePics;
    if (upchargePics>0){
        upchargePicsunits = Math.ceil((upchargePics)/10);
        upchargePicsCost = upchargePicsunits*40;
    }
    else {
        upchargePics = 0;
        upchargePicsunits = 0;
    }
    return upchargePics, upchargePicsCost;
}

function calcTotalCost(baseCost, timeCost, picsCost){
    return baseCost + timeCost + picsCost;
}

function print(retName, retPlan, baseCost, upchargeTime, upchargeTimeCost, upchargePics, upchargePicsCost, totalCost){
    document.write(retName + ", thanks for using Photosarus!" + "\n");
    document.write("<br><br>");
    document.write("You selected plan " + retPlan + " at a cost of "+ baseCost );
    document.write("<br><br>");
    document.write(upchargeTime + "additional hours at a cost of "+ upchargeTimeCost);
    document.write("<br><br>");
    document.write(upchargePics + "additional pictures at a cost of "+ upchargePicsCost);
}
```

I expect the output to say

Bill, thanks for using Photosarus!

You selected plan S at a cost of $450

0 additional hours at a cost of $0

0 additional pictures at a cost of $0

But instead I get

undefined, thanks for using Photosarus!

You selected plan undefined at a cost of undefined

undefined additional hours at a cost of undefined

undefined additional pictures at a cost of undefined

Comment: your functions don't return anything, that's why you are getting undefined vars.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `return` the values from the functions:

```
function getName(){
    var text;
    var name = prompt("Enter your name");
    if (name == null) {
        text = "Please enter a valid name";
    }
    return name;
}

function getPlan(plan){
    var plan = prompt("Enter the selected package");
    return plan;
}

function getHours(hours){
    var hours = prompt("Enter anticipated coverage hours");
    return hours;
}

function getPics(pics){
    var pics = prompt("Enter anticipated number of pictures");
    return pics;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it's always the small stuff ha. That works pretty well but the output is still a little messed up. The name and math all check out but the last 2 lines are 
_undefinedadditional hours at a cost of 7250

undefinedadditional pictures at a cost of 0_

Comment: Yes - you need to return the values in the correct format from the function.